# document.write < won't work unless I use &lt; what can I do instead to generate a link?

Tags: javascript, json, callback, youtube, document.write

this code only seems to work when I use `&lt;` instead of `<` and `&gt;` instead of `>` so how can I get it to work so that it links to the rightful video owner's channel.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function youtubeFeedCallback(json){
        document.write("&lt;a href='youtube.com/user/"+json["data"]["uploader"]+"'&gt;"+json["data"]["uploader"]+"&lt;/a&gt;");
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/4TSJhIZmL0A?v=2&alt=jsonc&callback=youtubeFeedCallback&prettyprint=true"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = json["data"]["uploader"], 
url = "youtube.com/user/" + text;
text.link(url);
```

Comment: just curious, do you know if this works in all browsers? mozilla developer center has it marked as 'non-standard' (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/link).

Comment: i've tested it in IE7-8, Firefox, Opera, Chrome and it does work. I've seen it here https://github.com/jed/140bytes/wiki/Byte-saving-techniques

Answer (score 1):

it would probably be better to use another injection method than `document.write()`, such as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function youtubeFeedCallback(json){
        var user = json.data.uploader,
            a = document.createElement("a");

        a.href = 'http://www.youtube.com/user/' + user;
        a.appendChild( document.createTextNode(user) );
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild( a );
    }        
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/4TSJhIZmL0A?v=2&alt=jsonc&callback=youtubeFeedCallback&prettyprint=true"></script>
```

you may need to change the location the link gets inserted in, but the idea is to move away from `document.write()` and use pure DOM insertion.

hope that helps. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

`json["data"]["uploader"]` may contains some invalid characters that spoils your html code. (Such as a single quote)